# Is os.path.isfile always the opposite of os.path.isdir for an existing file system object?

Tags: python, os.path

I am to list all the files and directories in a directory with `os.listdir` and tell them apart reliably. Is it ok to use just `os.path.isdir` and consider it's a file if it returns false or should I check `os.path.isfile` anyway? Are there cases when `os.path.exists(path) and os.path.isdir(path) == os.path.isfile(path)` happens to be true?

Comment: Depending on your OS and file system there can be more than just files and directories.

Comment: @KlausD. That's why I'm asking. Any examples?

Comment: For example on Linux you have devices, socket, named pipes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

os.path.isdir and os.path.isfile both are ok!  os.path.exists(path) and os.path.isdir(path) == os.path.isfile(path) is always False

Answer (score 1):

You should be all good to just use `os.path.isdir`. This only looks for if the path that is inputted is a directory. Otherwise, it is okay to assume it is a file. I have tested to see if any cases of when`os.path.exists(path) and os.path.isdir(path) == os.path.isfile(path)` Here are the results.

`print(os.path.isdir("C:\\Users\\Kobe Thompson\\Desktop\\Test\\"))
print(os.path.exists("C:\\Users\\Kobe Thompson\\Desktop\\Test\\"))
print(os.path.isfile("C:\\Users\\Kobe Thompson\\Desktop\\Test\\"))`

> True, True, False

```
print(os.path.isdir("C:\\Users\\Kobe Thompson\\Desktop\\Test\\test"))
print(os.path.exists("C:\\Users\\Kobe Thompson\\Desktop\\Test\\"))
print(os.path.isfile("C:\\Users\\Kobe Thompson\\Desktop\\Test\\"))
```

> False, True, False

```
print(os.path.isdir("C:\\Users\\Kobe Thompson\\Desktop\\Test\\test"))
print(os.path.exists("C:\\Users\\Kobe Thompson\\Desktop\\Test\\test"))
print(os.path.isfile("C:\\Users\\Kobe Thompson\\Desktop\\Test\\"))
```

> False, False, False

```
print(os.path.isdir("C:\\Users\\Kobe Thompson\\Desktop\\Test\\test"))
print(os.path.exists("C:\\Users\\Kobe Thompson\\Desktop\\Test\\test"))
print(os.path.isfile("C:\\Users\\Kobe Thompson\\Desktop\\Test\\test"))
```

False, False, False,

As you can see, there are some cases that can relate both of os.path.isdir and os.path.exists equal to os.path.isfile

Answer (score 0):

`os.path.isdir(path) == os.path.isfile(path)` should never hold in all disk file systems I am aware of, as this should mean that the same object is both a dir and a file. For [EXT4](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout) specifically, it is my understanding that an inode can either be a directory or a file.

However, the two functions [are not defined as mutually exclusive](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) as that would require an assumption about this being true in all possible filesystems, including future ones, and predictions about that are hard.

Comment: What are the unusual cases when it may?

Comment: Iff you are applying `filename.lower()` your filenames in `os.listdir('directory')`'s output, it can cause some hiccups. Since, in Ubuntu (16.04.4) you can do stuff like `mkdir Wtf; touch wtf;` in the same directory...